# jQuery Data Table with Back-end Pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I am current using Spring Data JPA for Pagination inside my Java Application on the back-end. So the RESTful service is called with parameters on the url like ?page=1 and ?size=100 to get the first page with 100 results.

Is there a way I can configure my jQuery Data Table on the UI so that it will invoke that back-end service change when the user changes the table?

For instance, initial call will be default page 1 and size 100. If they change the results per page in the table I want to change the size sent to the service to what ever the user selects. If they click the next page arrow I want to increment the page count on the service and call it to get the next page and etc.

We have too much data to just send all the data to the UI to hold and paginate on the front-end, which is why I want to follow this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can try some thing like the below:

```
 var table = $('#employeesTable').DataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": "/employees",
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "id"},
              { "mData": "name" },
                  { "mData": "lastName" },
                  { "mData": "email" },
                  { "mData": "phone" },
                  { "mData": "active" }
            ]
     })
```

below references might help you:

http://learnfromexamples.com/jquery-datatable-in-spring-mvc-application/
https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-jquery-datatables-a2e816e2b5e9

Comment: Tank you I will try that and see.